# I'm confused with Grid layout in ListBoxItem of WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, listboxitem

I'm newer in wpf,recently i have a requirement need to create an listbox and when i practice in DataTemplate ,the issue comed.my layout code like below

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
         <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Height="50">
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Width="200" Height="40" Fill="Gray"/>
         </Grid>
     </ListBoxItem>
 </ListBox>
```

the begining,i set the width 100 on the first column,because the Rectange's width become to 200,so the first column width become more greater than 100,what happend when the grid to measue the child element?i am confused about it ,because i put the code in an commen state it run normally.any one tell me ,thanks

Comment: You've set `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` on the Rectangle, so it spans both columns. As its `HorizontalAlignment` defaults to `Center` it is centered horinzontally relative to the whole Grid width. What are you expecting?

Comment: You are right ,the rectangle'location is in the center of the whole grid,i set the Grid property ShowGridLines to true,so we can see the grid line's location and the first column width is larger than 100,so it change bigger,it is different from my expect,why?

Comment: "first column width is larger than 100", how do you measure that?

Comment: i use the position of grid line to measure the column width.and at the design time the width had changed. when i set the max width of the ColumnDefinition to 100,the result is right.why?